# stand alone flash player

Tags: flash

I'm  running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 desktop lts and have downloaded the adobe stand alone player.

When i try to run it i get the error:-

> ./flashplayer ./flashplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

as far as i can tell i have the apropriate libraries installed but i'm guessing its looking for the x86 library but i don't know how to force install it.

how do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on x64, check you have the i386 repositories enabled:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

If you don't, add it via:

```
sudo dpkg  --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0` is provided by `libglib2.0-0` for me. To install the x86 version, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: I tried this. `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` outputs i386, and `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386` results in libglib2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version. Is there anything else we can try?

Comment: @ElderGeek is this thing still available? O.o You could try running `ldd` on the file to see what other libraries are missing.

Comment: Yes, still available although I've had no luck getting it working thus far. Gnash failed miserably for me (I think due to Action Script) I'm attempting another approach and will post an alternative answer once I ascertain that I can duplicate the results. (It may be awhile as my system is under heavy load and software center is currently hung)

Answer (score 1):

I also had difficulty getting this to work on 14.04 x64. Other approaches like gnash failed for me likely due to incomplete support for Action Script. Finally I used this approach:

1. Install latest Wine from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu or **simply install wine via the software center**.
2. Download The standalone flash player 12 from [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_12.0.0.38_archive.zip).
3. Extract to `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/` (You will have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files to find the `.wine` directory if you are using Archive Manager to extract).
4. Open `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/fp_12.0.0.38_archive/12_0_r0_38_debug` folder and launch 
   `flashplayer12_0r0_38_win_sa_debug.exe` with Wine windows program loader
5. Navigate to and open your .swf. From this point forward I was able to simply rightclick on an SWF file and choose open with Adobe Flash Player 12.0 r0

Sources: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1388144?tstart=0 and testing.